# IE 10/11 background position differences in links

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sprite, background-position

I'm a little bit confused to see differences in the CSS position of background images in those links in the welcome box ("International contacts" and "Go to contact page"). When you take a closer look, you will see, that the background-position-y is not the same (1px difference). 
https://bb-portal.mercedes-benz.com/portal/apps/ansprechpartner_db/?htmlStart

This phenomenon happens also on other places (unfortunately only visible with login). Any idea how this could happen?

Comment: Are you referring to .mod_ansprechpartnerdb_infobox?

Comment: Click on the link text with Firebug like described above and you will get something like ".mod_ansprechpartnerdb_infobox .bodytext a". There is no difference in the css code but the icon-arrow position still looks not the same in IE 10+

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. If you turn on IE's Compatibility View the problem disappears. OK, try removing the `<br>`'s and instead use `p` tags for your paragraphs about those links.

Comment: Very strange... but thanks indeed, your suggestion solves the problem.

Comment: Ok, BRs to p-Tags was one thing, but there is another place, where those strange behavings arrise: ul > li > a
Have a look here https://bb-portal.mercedes-benz.com/bic/ at the left menu. Everything is the same but some LIs render false.